# Modifying a dictionary in groovy to be passed to jinja

Tags: groovy

I have a dictionary in jenkinsfile something like with opening and closing brackets. Notice how it starts with "[" and ends with "]"-

> [1:{"key":"CI","value":"yash"},2:{"key":"CI","value":"ruben"},3:{"key":"CI","value":"Sam"}]

I want to convert this into something with opening and closing curly brackets.

> {1:{"key":"CI","value":"yash"},2:{"key":"CI","value":"ruben"},3:{"key":"CI","value":"Sam"}}

```
Dict = [1:
         {
          "key":"CI",
          "value":"yash"
         },
        2:
         {
          "key":"CI",
          "value":"ruben"
         }
       ]
```

Instead of this i want it to look like -

```
Dict = {1:
         {
          "key":"CI",
          "value":"yash"
         },
        2:
         {
          "key":"CI",
          "value":"ruben"
         }
       }
```

I tried using this
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(Dict)  but it hasn't helped.

Comment: You're going to have to show some example code.  It looks like you're talking about the string representation of a Map, but I can't tell from the question what type you have as an input, and what you require as an output

Comment: @tim_yates have edited the question to make it more meaningful.

Comment: Can you make it so it's actual groovy code that would compile?

Answer (score 0):

So your code you posted isn't Groovy.  If you changed your input to something like this:

```
dict = [
   1: [ "key": "CI", "value": "yash" ], 
   2: [ "key": "CI", "value": "ruben" ] 
]
println( JsonOutput.toJson( dict ) )
```

See the groovy doodle [here](http://tpcg.io/_XFZ6EK)

Comment: This wont work because i am trying to do this within the jenkinsfile.

Comment: You''l have to explain why you think groovy code won't work in Jenkins.  I was pretty sure Jenkinsfile is just Groovy code.

Comment: It keeps saying hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JsonOutput for class: WorkflowScript. I had already tried this @chubbsondubs

Comment: You have to import that object.  Did you check the Doodle I posted?  The first line imports the package that `JsonObject` lives in.  Without that your jenkins script can't find `JsonOutput`.  So you need to add `import groovy.json.*` at the top.